# What should we add to tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

What is the policy on creating/adding to tag wikis? I think this is of great importance, that we get some of the fundamental tags defined, such as Geology, Geophysics, and Geochemistry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subdiscipline tag convention](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/44/subdiscipline-tag-convention)

Comment: I don't really know what the question is here. All of those tags already exist - [geology](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geology), [geophysics](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geophysics), [geochemistry](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geochemistry). For other missing tags, why not just create the tags (assuming there are questions for the tags)?

Comment: i meant the wiki summary.

Comment: @Neo Oh, the tag wiki! Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 3):

Most of us know what the subdisciplines mean. But not everyone knows how to use the tags. So the tag wikis (and excerpts) should express **how the tag should be used**.

Citation of a stackexchange [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/):

> - The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag. You only have ~500 plain text characters for the excerpt, so don’t feel obligated to
>     cover everything in it! Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown
>     tag wiki. The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions
>     containing this tag — boiled down to a few short sentences.
> - Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized. The “email” tag, for example, does not need to
>     explain what email is. I think we can safely assume most internet
>     users know what email is; there’s no value in a boilerplate
>     explanation of email to anyone.
> - Concentrate on what a tag means to your community. For “email” on Server Fault, mention the server aspects of email including POP3,
>     SMTP, IMAP, and server software. For “email” on Super User, mention
>     desktop email clients and explicitly exclude webmail, as that would be
>     more appropriate for webapps.stackexchange.com.
> - Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag. In other words, what kinds of questions should have this tag? Tags only exist as ways of
>     organizing questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on which
>     questions need this tag, they won’t get tagged at all, rendering the
>     tag excerpt moot. Think of it as a sales pitch: in a room full of tags
>     screaming “pick me!”, what would convince a question asker to select
>     your tag?
> - Some tags are common knowledge. Most tags require a bit of explanation in the excerpt, even if it’s only 3 or 4 words. But if the
>     tag is common knowledge — that is, if you walked up to any random
>     person on the street and said the tag word to them, and they would
>     know what you were talking about — then don’t bother explaining the
>     tag at all. Stick to usage of the tag within your community in the
>     excerpt.